# How do I read a text file using the read() method?

Tags: java

Suppose my text file name is "FileToUse". How do I read this file byte by byte using the read method from the FileInputStream class?

My end goal is to create a HashMap with the key as the letter (but the byte for the letter would be the key) and the value as the number of times the letter was in the text file. Any tips on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you do:

1. First you create a file
2. Then, you link the file to the fileInputStream
3. If the file links then you assign the file contents one by one using the read() at the same time checking if it isn't the EOF. read() returns -1 for EOF
4. Then you process the contents into the map

   ```
   File file = new File("FileToUse.txt");
   FileInputStream fis = null;

       try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(file);

           System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                   + fis.available());

           int content;
           while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
               // process the content into the hashmap
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               if (fis != null)
                   fis.close();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome! So say I have HashMap<Byte, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Byte, Integer>(). Would it be correct to add a new key with "hashmap.put(content, 1)" and add an existing key with "hashmap.put(content, hashmap.get(content) + 1)"?

Comment: Yes! That should work

Comment: Great then, thanks!

Comment: Eclipse has me casting content as a byte like so, "hashmap.put((byte) content, 1). Is this still going to add the correct byte for its corresponding letter?

Comment: Java can not implicitly convert from int to byte so you will have to explicitly tell it to do so by saying that. So, I think it is okay to do so unless your file has something other than ascii. If so, then your code won't work due to overflow and you will have to choose some other data, possibly an integer.